# How find reinstall/replace Grub2 menu generation scripts

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, grub2

I'm trying to figure out how to reinstall/get copies of the scripts that Ubuntu has in the `/etc/grub.d/` folder. The scripts have names like `00_header` and `05_debian_theme`. They're used when the command `update-grub` is run, to generate the Grub2 menu listing.

I was playing around with some customization stuff, and accidentally deleted all of the scripts (well, actually I deliberately deleted them, assuming that reinstalling the `grub-pc` package would replace them. Bad assumption!)

Does anyone know how to reinstall all the default Grub2 scripts that Ubuntu 12.04 ships with? Or, failing that, can someone point me to a resource to get the contents of the scripts? (I'm plenty willing to copy-paste them in...I don't want to have to reinstall all of Ubuntu for this silly mistake.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing and reinstalling grub2-common should do the trick. Try:

```
sudo apt-get purge grub2-common
sudo apt-get install grub2-common
```

---

In general, you can find what files a package installs either through Synaptic (Right click on a package => Properties => Installed Files), or by running `dpkg -L <package_name>`.

In your case, you know that it has to be one of the grub related packages and you need to know which one installed `00_header`, for example. First, list all grub related packages, then search for `00_header` in the list of files that each of them installs:

1. Find what grub related packages are installed:

   ```
   $ dpkg -l grub* | grep ii
   ```
2. Find which of them installs `00_header` :

   ```
   $ for n in $(dpkg -l grub* | grep ii | awk '{print $2}'); do echo  "$n :  `dpkg -L $n | grep 00_`"; done
   ```

Comment: Awesome! That did it. (Also, I bow to your shell-fu! I wish I had your level of bash wizardry.)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked @IsaacDontjeLindell. As for shell-fu, use linux for work and play for more than a decade or so and it creeps up on you :)